# What is the Green's function in an infinite long rectangle?

Tags: boundary-value-problem, greens-function

Background: I study a massive quantum field in 1 dimension space with length 2L.  The wave functional of ground state is:
$$\Psi[\phi(x)]\propto\int D[\phi]e^{-1/2\int\dot{\phi}^2+(\nabla \phi)^2+u^2 \phi^2 dx dt}$$

where boundary condition is:
$$\phi(x,t=0)=\phi(x)$$
and the path integral is define in the area:
$$t>0,\quad -L<x<L$$

To get the part which is related to $\phi(x)$, I divide the $\phi(x,t)$ into two part:

$$\phi(x,t)=\phi_{c}(x,t)+\phi'(x,t)$$

Then I specify part of the boundary condtion for $\phi_{c}(x,t)$:
$$\phi_{c}(x,t=0)=\phi(x)$$

Thus the corresponding boundary condition for $\phi'$ is:
$$\phi'(x,t=0)=0$$

The integral becomes:

$$\int dx dt[\dot{\phi_c}^2+(\nabla \phi_c)^2+u^2 \phi_c^2]+[\dot{\phi'}^2+(\nabla \phi')^2+u^2 \phi'^2]+[2\dot{\phi_c}\dot{\phi'}+2\nabla \phi_c\nabla \phi'+2u^2 \phi_c\phi']$$

To get rid of the terms in the last square bracket, I can use the freedom of divide the $\phi$ into 2 parts and impose the boundary condition properly.

After integration by part, the last square bracket becomes:

$$\int dx (2\dot{\phi_c}\phi')|^{+\infty}_{t=0}+\int dt (2\nabla \phi_c \phi')|^{L}_{x=-L}+\int dx dt [-2\ddot{\phi_c}-2\nabla^2\phi_c+2u^2\phi_c]\phi'$$

By demanding that:

$$\dot{\phi_c}(x,t=+\infty)=0, \quad \nabla \phi_c(x=\pm L)=0,\quad -2\ddot{\phi_c}-2\nabla^2\phi_c+2u^2\phi_c=0$$

we can get rid of the square bracket.

Then the path integral becomes:

$$\Psi[\phi(x)]\propto e^{-1/2\int[ \dot{\phi_c}^2+(\nabla \phi_c)^2+u^2 \phi_c^2 ]dx dt }\int D[\phi]e^{-1/2\int\dot{\phi}^2+(\nabla \phi)^2+u^2 \phi^2 dx dt}$$

The path integral part is totally a number independent of $\phi(x)$ thus we can drop it:

$$\Psi[\phi(x)]\propto e^{-1/2\int[ \dot{\phi_c}^2+(\nabla \phi_c)^2+u^2 \phi_c^2 ]dx dt }$$

with condition:

$$\quad -2\ddot{\phi_c}-2\nabla^2\phi_c+2u^2\phi_c=0,\quad \phi_c(x,t=0)=\phi(x)$$
$$\dot{\phi_c}(x,t=+\infty)=0, \quad \nabla \phi_c(x=\pm L)=0$$

Use the Equation of motion:
$$\quad -2\ddot{\phi_c}-2\nabla^2\phi_c+2u^2\phi_c=0$$

By integrating by part, the integral becomes:

$$e^{1/2\int dx \phi_c(x)\dot{\phi_c(x)}}$$

The integration is done alone t=0.

---

MATH Part:
Finally comes the pure math part, to solve the PDE:

$$\quad -2\ddot{\phi_c}-2\nabla^2\phi_c+2u^2\phi_c=0,\quad \phi_c(x,t=0)=\phi(x)$$
$$\dot{\phi_c}(x,t=+\infty)=0, \quad \nabla \phi_c(x=\pm L)=0$$

I use Green's function.
$$(\partial_t^2 +\partial_x^2- u^2)G(x,t_1;y,t_2)=\delta(x-y,t_1-t_2)$$

The boundary condtion of $\phi_c$ demands the corresponding boundary condtion for $G$ to be:

$$\partial_tG(x,t_1=+\infty,y,t_2)=0,\quad G(x,t_1=0;y,t_2)=0$$
$$\partial_x G(x=\pm L,t_1;y,t_2)=0$$

I don't know how to solve it, wish some help me solve it.